# How to create a new procedure from bash script

Tags: bash, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a new PL/SQL Procedure in Oracle DB. The Procedure is to be created by a BASH script. Later-on the Procedure will be executed from the same BASH script.

There are ways to execute the stored procedure from bash script but none explains how to create a stored procedure form a bash script.

```
backup_procedure_string="CREATE OR REPLACE 
 PROCEDURE BACKUP_TABLE_PROCEDURE(
                .
                .
 END BACKUP_TABLE_PROCEDURE;"

backup_procedure_execution_string="BACKUP_TABLE_PROCEDURE('${param1}', '${param2}', '${param3}');"

sqlplus -S "${ofca_connect_string}" << EOF >> "${current_directory}/query.log"
        WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
        SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
        SET TERMOUT OFF
        $backup_procedure_string
                EXECUTE $backup_procedure_execution_string
        SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF 
        EXIT;
EOF
```

The Procedure "BACKUP_TABLE_PROCEDURE" should be created in the Database and gets executed. However, there is no error/oracle error but the procedure is also not getting created.

Comment: Do you miss a `COMMIT;`?

Comment: What is the reason to create a procedure and then execute it? If you know the logic of `BACKUP_TABLE_PROCEDURE` then execute it in an anonymous PL/SQL block. Or create the procedure manually in database and just execute it from bash.

Comment: no need to commit DDL

Comment: I think the main issue is missing a '/' on its own line after the procedure end. That's how you actually execute/compile the code.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me, here's a complete code sample.

Note I used SQLcl not SQLPlus, but same concept.

No idea what you have in your . . code, so maybe problem is there?

```
Jeffreys-Mini:19.1 thatjeffsmith$ procedure_string="CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SO_BASH is BEGIN
> null;
> END SO_BASH;
> /
> "
Jeffreys-Mini:19.1 thatjeffsmith$ echo $procedure_string
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SO_BASH is BEGIN null; END SO_BASH; /
Jeffreys-Mini:19.1 thatjeffsmith$ sql hr/oracle << EOF >> so.log
> $procedure_string
> EXIT;
> EOF
Jeffreys-Mini:19.1 thatjeffsmith$ more so.log

SQLcl: Release 18.3 Production on Fri Jun 14 10:16:57 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Jun 14 2019 10:16:58 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0



Procedure SO_BASH compiled


Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.3.0.0.0
Jeffreys-Mini:19.1 thatjeffsmith$
```

And browsing my schema...

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The above solution by  @thatjeffsmith resolved the issue. I was missing the last "/" character in my procedure_string.